# Why doesn't a method reference keep track of this?

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I am using Babel to transpile an ES2015 class:

```
class Foo {
    constructor(foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    sayFoo() {
        console.log(this.foo);
    }
}
```

This class works exactly as I expect if I say something like `fooVar.sayFoo()`. However, if I try to treat the method like a typical JavaScript function and pass it as a parameter (`element.click(fooVar.sayFoo)`), when the method actually runs its lexical `this` is the event object, not the instance of `Foo`, so the `this.foo` is undefined.

Instead, since I specified an instance of `Foo`, I expected `fooVar.sayFoo` to be bound to the value of `fooVar`. I have to write an extra wrapper function for this to work as I expect.

I tried to look through the ES6 spec but couldn't figure out the scoping rules. Is this strange scoping behavior correct according to spec, or is it a bug somewhere (e.g., in Babel)?

Comment: There's no magic happening there, the `this` value of a function depends on the execution context, i.e. how it's called, not how it's defined, always has, nothing to do with ES2015. When referencing a function like that, the element is set as the `this` value.

Comment: You don't have to write an extra wrapper function, you can use bind https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind `element.click(fooVar.sayFoo.bind(fooVar))`

Comment: @adeneo As the entire "class" system is new, I expected the expression `fooVar.sayFoo` to already be bound to `fooVar`--the alternative that Joseph posted seems to me to ought to have been the automatic behavior. I'll just chalk this up to more JavaScript idiosyncrasy; thanks.

Comment: Class or no class doesn't matter, Babel probably transpiles that into an object literal anyway, but execution context is still what sets the `this` value, anything else would break the internet, just think of all the event handlers with referenced functions that would stop working.

Comment: Binding is expensive, doing it automatically for every function, even when you don't need it, would slow down your code with no way to optimize it.

Comment: The answer to your question seems to be: Because the spec says so, or, because someone decided to do it so. Browsers can optimize prototypes, auto-binding would kind of defeat the purpose of having prototypes I guess.

Comment: The class system isn't really that new, I think it's mostly syntactic sugar on top of the old prototype stuff.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about language specification design decisions.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Automatic binding doesn't need to be expensive if it were actually supported by the language. A half-competent JIT would be able to treat most method calls the same as now, so overhead would mostly only exist in cases where an explicit bind() call would already have been necessary. Some patterns would need to change, but the JavaScript community doesn't seem to have a problem with rebuilding the world from scratch every few years. Automatic binding simply doesn't exist because the motivation was not to redesign the object model from scratch, but only to sugar the existing one.

Comment: @FelixKling I'll dispute closure. I stated a clearly answerable question: "Is this the correct behavior, even though it seems weird?" I'm not asking for an opinion from the language designers.

Comment: OK. The title seems to ask for something else.

Comment: @Barmar I understand that, but one naive approach would expect the sugar underlying `instance.method` to return a function already bound to the instance.

Comment: @chrylis The problem is that `instance.method` already has a meaning, so changing that would be an incompatibililty. They could have added a new syntax that does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this the correct behavior, even though it seems weird?

Yes. Methods are more or less syntactic sugar for functions assigned to `prototype` properties.

Only arrow functions treat `this` differently.

Instead of writing a wrapper function, however, you can explicitly bind the instance to the method:

```
element.click(fooVar.sayFoo.bind(fooVar));
```

See also [How to access the correct `this` / context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)