# Updating component to reflect changes in data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, state

Trying to create a new Note in "Create" component sent a POST request and added it to the database. Now I need the change to be reflected in the state of "App" component.

Solution: On submission of Note (Create Comp) to the database, a copy of the object is sent to App.js, where we update note property in state so that it reflects the change in the database.

Issue: Getting a few errors, problem lines are labeled in the code.

[image]

```html
class App extends Component{
  state = {
    notes: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/notes')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({notes: data}))
  }

  onSubmitUpdateState(newNote){
    const oldState = [...this.state.notes]
    // Problem 2)
    this.setState({notes: [...oldState, newNote]});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Notes notes={this.state.notes}/>
        <Create updateState={this.onSubmitUpdateState}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classes from './Create.module.css';

class Create extends Component{
  state= {
    title: "",
    body: ""
  }
  
  onChange = (e)=>{
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }
  handleSubmit = (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const post = {
      title: this.state.title,
      body: this.state.body
    }
    // Problem 1
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/notes', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => this.props.updateState(data))
    this.setState({
      title: "",
      body: ""
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className={classes.CreateContainer}>
        <div className={classes.Create}>
            <h1>Create</h1>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>Title:</label><br/>
                <input type="text" name="title" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.title}></input><br/>
                <label>Body:</label><br/>
                <textarea row="8" col="50" name="body" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.body}></textarea><br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
            </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
} 
export default Create;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, [class methods are not bounded by default](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/), this SO answer talks about [why is it like that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127519/why-arent-methods-of-an-object-created-with-class-bound-to-it-in-es6)

If you're not using arrow function, make sure to `bind()` your event handlers to access `this`.

```
<Create
  updateState={this.onSubmitUpdateState.bind(this)} // pass a binded handler
/>
```

Comment: Why is this happening that `this` is not the component App without binding?

Comment: It's just how javascript [works](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/01/understanding-javascript-function-prototype-bind/). Class methods are not bounded by default.

Answer (score 3):

Use **Arrow function** or **bind** your action, if you are using **this.state** in any of method.

**Arrow Function :**

```
  onSubmitUpdateState = (newNote) => {
    const oldState = [...this.state.notes]
    // Problem 2)
    this.setState({notes: [...oldState, newNote]});
  }
```

**bind method :**
Create constructor and add this line in your constructor

```
 this.onSubmitUpdateState = this.onSubmitUpdateState.bind(this)
```

Without constructor

```
<Create updateState={this.onSubmitUpdateState.bind(this)}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this

```
class App extends Component{
  state = {
    notes: []
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/notes')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({notes: data}))
  }



  onSubmitUpdateState = (newNote) => {   //change to arrow function//
    const oldState = [...this.state.notes]
    // Problem 2)
    this.setState({notes: [...oldState, newNote]});
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <Notes notes={this.state.notes}/>
        <Create updateState={this.onSubmitUpdateState}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

The arrow syntax takes care of the `this` binding for you. Or you can `bind` the function inside constructor. `

Basically arrow functions preserve `this` context when they are called

Answer (score 1):

The error is complaining that `this.state` is undefined, you may need to pass the function `this.onSubmitUpdateState` as arrow function

I am not sure though why is this not bounded when function passed as props

```
<Create updateState={()=> this.onSubmitUpdateState()}/>
```

there is another answer that [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127519/why-arent-methods-of-an-object-created-with-class-bound-to-it-in-es6) why is it happening so.